# Apex in Vscode for Extend Keyword

Tags: apex, vs-code

I want to write a code for Extends keyword in apex using the sobject Contact.I am new to this.Can any one tell me how to run this code in vscode. When I try to run this Code, I got this error.

> ERROR: Line: 1, Column: 1
>
> classes are by default virtual
>   ERROR running force:apex:execute:  Line: 1, Column: 1
>
> classes are by default virtual
>   10:44:02.402 sfdx force:apex:execute --apexcodefile c:\Users\Vaasini\Documents\Sample Project.sfdx\tools\tempApex.input
>    ended with exit code 1

My code:
**

```
public virtual  class fetchContact {
    public virtual void getContact(){
        Contact contact1 = [Select Id,Name FROM Contact where (LastName = 'Yona')];
        system.debug(contact1);
    }
}
```

```
public with sharing class contactUpdation extends fetchContact{
    public override void getContact(){
        Contact contact1 = [ Select Phone FROM Contact where (LastName = 'Yona')];     
        contact1.Phone='999999999';
        update contact1;
        system.debug(contact1);
    }
}
```

```
public with sharing class createContact extends fetchContact{
    Contact contact2;
    public override void getcontact(){
        Contact contact1 = [Select Id,FirstName,LastName,Phone from Contact where Name = 'Yona'];
        Contact contact2 = new Contact();
        contact2.FirstName = 'Lydia';
        contact2.LastName = Contact1.LastName;
        contact2.Phone = '9876543210';
        contact2.AccountId =('0012x000005ydxwAAA') ;
        contact2.Description = ('Created using existing contact but with differet Phone number and Account');
        Insert contact2;
        System.debug(contact2);
    }
}
```

```
fetchContact objfetch, objcreate, objupdate; 
objfetch = new fetchContact(); 
objfetch.getContact();
objupdate = new contactUpdation(); 
objupdate.getContact(); objcreate = new createContact();
objcreate.getContact();
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the class is already virtual, so just remove the virtual keyword on the class:

```
public class fetchContact {
    public virtual void getContact(){
        Contact contact1 = [Select Id,Name FROM Contact where (LastName = 'Yona')];
        system.debug(contact1);
    }
}
```